# Bookmarker that saves the page HTML for offline archive

Tags: web-browser, bookmark, archiving

Looking for a browser extension that bookmarks a page and also saves a copy of it so that even if the page goes offline, or I go offline, I can still view it.

Sort of like a "save page as HTML" feature but with the accessibility of a bookmark so that you can view the page directly from the browser, either the live version if available, or from the offline archive.

It should be an extension for Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Scrapbook (Firefox)

This extension is quite famous, it has even got a [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ScrapBook). The following description is from Firefox add-ons:

> ScrapBook is a Firefox extension, which helps you to save Web pages
>   and easily manage collections. Key features are lightness, speed,
>   accuracy and multi-language support. Major features are:
>
> - Save Web page
> - Save snippet of Web page
> - Save Web site
> - Organize the collection in the same way as Bookmarks
> - Full text search and quick filtering search of the collection
> - Editing of the collected Web page
> - Text/HTML edit feature resembling Opera's Notes

[image: Scrapbook screenshot]

#### [→ Download page ←](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrapbook/)

## Scrapbook (Chrome)

This one is from a different author, but it mimics most of the functionalities:

> #### Features
>
> - No service to subscribe to, total privacy to store your annotations. Simple SQL based webstorage at backend.
> - Easy folder based access right from the extension's pop up. The storage is completely offline.
> - Undo and remove. Add Sticky Notes to pages.
> - Deletion of pages is supported.
> - Easy management using the options menu.

[image: Scrapbook screenshot]

#### [→ Download page ←](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scrapbook/fihabipakbgncingdhhdidlbhneeicne)

## Pocket (Offline mode available only on Chrome)

[Pocket](http://getpocket.com) is an online bookmarking service which was previously known as *Read It Later*. It can be used to bookmark and sync links across devices, including Android and iOS smartphones. It features browser extensions for Firefox and Chrome, however those are only useful to save articles, not to read them.

On Chrome, you can install the official Pocket app (different from the Pocket extension) that works offline:

> #### What can I save?
>
> Save articles, videos, recipes, and webpages you find
>   online or from your favorite apps.
>
> #### View everywhere, even offline
>
> If it’s in Pocket, it’s on your phone, tablet or computer, even when
>   you’re offline. Perfect for commutes, travel, and curling up on your
>   couch.
>
> #### Better viewing experience
>
> See your saved items in a simple,
>   easy-to-view layout that improves the viewing experience of any page.
>
> #### Works offline
>
> Access what you’ve saved offline. Set up Pocket to only
>   download when connected to Wi-Fi to reduce data usage.

[image: Pocket screenshot]

#### [→ Download page ←](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pocket/mjcnijlhddpbdemagnpefmlkjdagkogk)

Comment: BTW browsers also have a [offline mode](https://addyosmani.com/blog/offline-mode-chrome/) which can be used with bookmarks.

Comment: This is really awesome! And thanks for the offline mode tip as well! Can't believe I didn't know the true potential of that feature till now, I always thought why or how the hell would anyone use a freaking browser offline!? :P.

Comment: Also I came across this fork [scrapbook-x](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrapbook-x) which claims to be more actively maintained.

Comment: Eh eh. :) BTW for reading articles I often use Pocket, while for researching purpose (or medium-long term archiving) I normally use Evernote. It doesn't have an official app for Linux but I sync it with my phone and tablet.

Comment: @laggingreflex nice alternative. You may consider adding it as an answer as well.